# C++ Windows Service Error 1063

Tags: c++, service, startup

Trying to develop my first windows service, and I'm debugging in windows 7 MS VC++ 10.0. As soon as it calls, StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(), I get an error 1063 and it says Access is Denied. I am administrator, how exactly do I get passed this? I'm new to services. Thanks. Code:

```
// For WinXp, don't forget to link to
// Advapi32.lib library if needed...

#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501

#include <windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// Prototypes, just empty skeletons...

void SvcDebugOut(LPSTR String, DWORD Status);
void  WINAPI MyServiceCtrlHandler(DWORD opcode);
void  MyServiceStart(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv);
DWORD MyServiceInitialization(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv, DWORD *specificError);

void main() 
{

       // Using 2-D array as a table...

       // The name of a service to be run in this service process - "MyService",

       // The function as the starting point for a service - MyServiceStart or

       // a pointer to a ServiceMain() function...

       // The members of the last entry in the table must have NULL values

       // to designate the end of the table...

       SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY  DispatchTable[] = {{_TEXT("MyService"), (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)MyServiceStart}, {NULL, NULL}};
   if (!StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(DispatchTable))
       SvcDebugOut("StartServiceCtrlDispatcher() failed, error: %d\n", GetLastError());
   else
       printf("StartServiceCtrlDispatcher() looks OK.\n");
   return;
} 

// ==========================================================================
// Prototype definitions...just skeletons here...
void  WINAPI MyServiceCtrlHandler(DWORD opcode)
{
       // Service control information here...
       return;
}

void  MyServiceStart(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv)
{
       // Starting service information here...
       return;
}



DWORD MyServiceInitialization(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv, DWORD *specificError)
{
       // Service initialization information here...
       return 0;
}

// Very simple info to the standard output...
void SvcDebugOut(LPSTR String, DWORD Status)
{
   CHAR  Buffer[1024];
   printf("In SvcDebugOut() lol!\n");
   if (strlen(String) < 1000)
   {
      sprintf(Buffer, String, Status);
      OutputDebugStringA(Buffer);
   }
   else 
      printf("String too long...\n");
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732815/startservicectrldispatcher-dont-can-access-1063-error) answers correctly. As long as you do not start the service "as a service" it will not work.

You need to register it. To do so, look at this [file](http://opensource.apple.com/source/mDNSResponder/mDNSResponder-333.10/mDNSWindows/SystemService/Service.c), it is the Apple bonjour service implementation, which is open source.

It gives a good idea of what must be done to install a service. Especially the method InstallService - and RemoveService (if you want to remove it).

Answer (score 1):

Services run under the account that is specified in the properties of their registration. It might not be the same to the account that registered the service or started it. Reads about this.

Many services run under "Network service" account that has very limited capabilities. This makes sense because many services process requests that come from the network. This is why this very low privileged "Network service" was selected by Microsoft as the default.

Answer (score 0):

**THE APPROACH**

The following link below shows an example of a working basic 'Hello World' type of Windows Service from Microsoft's Web Site which can compile as 32-bit or 64-bit (hence the _tmain which translates to main or wmain depending on the compiler setting).

With most modern Windows Servers today, you should be only compiling your apps as 64-bit Services for efficiency and larger memory requirement usage availability as needed:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/writing-a-service-program-s-main-function

The **'main()'** (or in this example '_tmain') or **WinMain()** is not what executes when a Windows Service is started, but instead a **ServiceMain()** is executed to **Start**, **Pause**, or **Stop** your Application.

The 'main()' function is only used if you want to **"Self Register"** or **"Self UnRegister"** your Windows Service with the **Service Control Manager (SCM)** by running it from a command line console using control keywords like **'install'** or **'uninstall'** next to the executable name and having your **'main()'** function handle acting one them to **'register'** or **'unregister'** with the **SCM** (also called 'Scum' as a nickname).

**SECURITY**

Kirill Kobelev does make a point above related to who the Service should run as.
Typically, **"Network Service"** is often good enough for good practice in security.

If you need to give your Service explicit access to specific things in the Registry or on the File System which only your Service should need, then you can set the Service to run using as a **"Service Level" Account**.

A **"Service Level" Account** should use a long password using a GUID so it is difficult to deciefer.  Also, it should:

- Never expire the account and
- Never require the password to be changed

...or your **"Windows Service" will no longer Start** when you reboot the machine or restart it later.