# StartServiceCtrlDispatcher don't can access 1063 error

Tags: c++, winapi, service

I write on c++ service , but have error, and don't can fixed it.

my service main function

```
int main (int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{DWORD f;
    for(int i=0;i<113;i++)
        f = GetLastError();
    servicePath = LPTSTR(argv[0]);
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: Main: Entry"));
    //InstallService();
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceTable[] = 
    {
        {SERVICE_NAME, (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION) ServiceMain},
        {NULL, NULL}
    };
//  StartService();
    if(!StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(ServiceTable)) {
         f = GetLastError();
      //addLogMessage("Error: StartServiceCtrlDispatcher");

  } else if( memcmp(argv[argc-1],"install",7)) {
    InstallService();
  } else if( memcmp(argv[argc-1],"remove",6)) {
    RemoveService();
  } else if( memcmp(argv[argc-1],"start",5)) {
    StartService();
  } else if( memcmp(argv[argc-1],"stop",4))  {
    // StopService();
  }
//  StopService();
    OutputDebugString(_TEXT("My Sample Service: Main: Exit"));
    return 0;
}
```

Where I debug my programm with command line arguments (service_path and action) on StartServiceCtrlDispatcher every time return 1063 error. Visual Studio I run under Administrator. Where I write wrong code, please help.

**UPDATE**

```
VOID WINAPI ServiceMain (DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv)
{
    DWORD Status = E_FAIL;

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Entry"));

    g_StatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler (SERVICE_NAME, ServiceCtrlHandler);

    if (g_StatusHandle == NULL) 
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: RegisterServiceCtrlHandler returned error"));
        goto EXIT;
    }

    // Tell the service controller we are starting
    ZeroMemory (&g_ServiceStatus, sizeof (g_ServiceStatus));
    g_ServiceStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_START_PENDING;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;

    if (SetServiceStatus (g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE) 
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
    }

    /* 
     * Perform tasks neccesary to start the service here
     */
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Performing Service Start Operations"));

    // Create stop event to wait on later.
    g_ServiceStopEvent = CreateEvent (NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (g_ServiceStopEvent == NULL) 
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: CreateEvent(g_ServiceStopEvent) returned error"));

        g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = GetLastError();
        g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 1;

        if (SetServiceStatus (g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE)
        {
            OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
        }
        goto EXIT; 
    }    

    // Tell the service controller we are started
    g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;

    if (SetServiceStatus (g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE)
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
    }

    // Start the thread that will perform the main task of the service
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread (NULL, 0, ServiceWorkerThread, NULL, 0, NULL);

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Waiting for Worker Thread to complete"));

    // Wait until our worker thread exits effectively signaling that the service needs to stop
    WaitForSingleObject (hThread, INFINITE);

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Worker Thread Stop Event signaled"));


    /* 
     * Perform any cleanup tasks
     */
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Performing Cleanup Operations"));

    CloseHandle (g_ServiceStopEvent);

    g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 3;

    if (SetServiceStatus (g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE)
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
    }

    EXIT:
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceMain: Exit"));

    return;
}

VOID WINAPI ServiceCtrlHandler (DWORD CtrlCode)
{
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceCtrlHandler: Entry"));

    switch (CtrlCode) 
    {
     case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP :

        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceCtrlHandler: SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP Request"));

        if (g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_RUNNING)
           break;

        /* 
         * Perform tasks neccesary to stop the service here 
         */

        g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 4;

        if (SetServiceStatus (g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE)
        {
            OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceCtrlHandler: SetServiceStatus returned error"));
        }

        // This will signal the worker thread to start shutting down
        SetEvent (g_ServiceStopEvent);

        break;

     default:
         break;
    }

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceCtrlHandler: Exit"));
}

DWORD WINAPI ServiceWorkerThread (LPVOID lpParam)
{
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceWorkerThread: Entry"));

    main2();

    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceWorkerThread: Exit"));

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Since we cannot see `ServiceMain` we cannot know what's wrong. Except for the obvious undefined behavior due to accessing unallocated memory (`memcmp(argv[argc-1],"install",7)`).

Comment: update add ServiceMain function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` when your process was started by the Service Control Manager, i.e., when it is actually running as a service.  When called from any other context, you will get `ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT` (1063).

From the looks of your code, you should only be calling `StartServiceControlDispatcher` if no command-line argument was passed, e.g., something like

```
if (argc < 2)
{
  if (!StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(ServiceTable)) 
  {
    f = GetLastError();
  }
} 
else if (strcmp(argv[1], "install")
{
  InstallService();
}
```

and so on.

---

There are also some other problems with your main() function, most notably:

- The wrong signature; argv[] is char, not TCHAR
- Casting argv[0] to TCHAR
- A loop which calls GetLastError for no reason, 114 times
- The use of memcmp instead of strcmp

I didn't look at ServiceMain().

Answer (score 4):

it happen when the  service is installed over windows 8, or later, of 64 bits and is invoked the method **StartServiceCtrlDispatcher** which will invoke the Main entry point. But the method **StartServiceCtrlDispatcher** works with pointer of 8 bits.

So, the solution is to use the function **StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW** which works with pointers of 16 bits, for example:

Before: it uses the pointer to **LPTSTR** (8 bits), that is the type of data that need **SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY** and **StartServiceCtrlDispatcher**:

```
SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY DispatchTable[] = {
            { (LPTSTR)srvName.str().c_str(), (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain },
            { NULL,NULL }
        };
StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(DispatchTable);
```

After: it uses the pointer to **LPWSTR** (16 bits), that is the type of data that need **SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYW** and **StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW**:

```
SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYW DispatchTable[] = {
            { (LPWSTR)srvName.str().c_str(), (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain },
            { NULL,NULL }
        };
StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW(DispatchTable);
```

Conclusion:

Use the wide string (16 bits per char) and the functions of StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW and SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYW Type instead of StartServiceCtrlDispatcher and SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY.

Comment: Also, i notice that there is neccesary check if it use wstring and wchar, like that:

wstring wAux = srvName.str();
   LPWSTR wSrv = (LPWSTR)wAux.c_str();
   SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYW DispatchTable[] = {
    { wSrv, (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain },
    { NULL,NULL }
   };
   StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW(DispatchTable);

Comment: `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` is a macro that expands to either `StartServiceCtrlDispatcherA` or `StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW` depending on the build settings.  Unless the service name contains non-ASCII characters, it does not matter which one you use, though of course you must provide a string of the right type.  Visual Studio defaults to wide characters anyway, in which case your two code fragments are identical.

Comment: It is not exactly identical, in the case `StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW` it use a pointer to wide-string `LPWSTR` meanwhile `StartServiceCtrlDispatcherA` use `LPSTR` . That is the reason to have Access Memory Exceptions. https://source.winehq.org/source/include/winsvc.h#0214

Comment: Your first code fragment uses `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` which, if you are using the default build settings (which you should) is a macro for `StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW`.  So if you're doing everything right, they're *exactly* the same.  On the other hand, there *is* an advantage to making sure that the code fails to build if the wrong settings are used.  The best way to do that IMO is to use a string literal so you can get rid of the cast.

Comment: ... anyway, my point is that this has nothing to do with Windows 8 or whether you're running 32-bit or 64-bit Windows, and it doesn't actually make any difference whether you use `StartServiceCtrlDispatcherA` or `StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW` *just so long as you provide a string of the right type*.  If `srvName.str()` returned a narrow string, `StartServiceCtrlDispatcherA` would work and `StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW` wouldn't.  It just has to match.

Comment: Ok, i understand. I need to say that, in my case, the fist code was the problem and i fix it with the second code. And your are right, the main issue is to take care of what type of data is used with the setting, all of this to avoid using the wrong data that can originate access memory exceptions. Thanks for your feedback.